# MongoDB: Aggregation create ISODate from DateTime String

Tags: mongodb, datetime, aggregation-framework, projection, isodate

I am using the MongoDB aggregation framework to group, sort and project some stuff from my database. The element of my result array looks like the following

```
{
  someField: "someField",
  timestamp: "2017-12-05T19:00:00.000Z"
}
```

The aggregation pipeline step I struggle with looks like the following

```
{
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    someField: 1,
    timestamp: '$_id.timestamp',
  }
}
```

I want to convert that DateTime string into an ISODate. If I use `ISODate('$timestamp')` the mongo client returns the error `Invalid ISODate`.
Another approach was to use just `Date('$timestamp')`, just returns the my local date as if I would be using `Date()`. Nevertheless if I enter `print(ISODate("2017-12-05T19:00:00.000Z"))` directly into the mongo client everything is working as expected.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: We're using Mongo 3.4. Version 3.6 offers a solution, but I am not sure if we can upgrade to 3.6. (See answer below)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new [`$dateFromString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) operator available in 3.6.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "timestamp": {
        "$dateFromString": {
          "dateString": "$timestamp"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for Mongo 3.6+. Rn I'm not sure if we can upgrade from 3.4 to 3.6. Is there a 3.4 solution as well?